# Websocketpp set message handler

Tags: c++, websocket

I am setting the on-message handler like this and it works.

```
srv.set_message_handler(&on_message);

// This works     
void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg_ptr)
{

}
```

However, when I create a class and put the `on_message` function in that class and try to `set_message_handler` I get an error. The `srv` variable in this case is a class member. Something like this:

```
class Server
{
public:
    typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

    void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, 
                    server::message_ptr msg_ptr);
private:
    server srv;
};
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Shiro\ClionProjects\Thesis\source_files\Server.cpp: In constructor 'Server::Server(short unsigned int, const Graph&, const Graph&)':
C:\Users\Shiro\ClionProjects\Thesis\source_files\Server.cpp:10:37: error: no matching function for call to 'websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio>::set_message_handler(void (Server::*)(Server::connection_handler, Server::message_ptr))'
     s.set_message_handler(&on_message);
                                     ^
```

How can I work this out ? I want my `on_message` function to be inside a `Server` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it like this solved the problem:

```
// using boost::bind
server.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message, this, ::_1, ::_2));
```